# Why ECS service keeps producing wrong log stream infinitely?

Tags: logging, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I update the code and redployed one of my services on ECS that I hadn't touched for a long time. After restart, the service works fine. But I noticed one issue about the log streams. Besides the correct logstream for this latest modification task (If I click into this specific task, the logging is fine), there are many other log streams that are constantly created [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQFm9.png) And if I click into the tasks of these wrong logstream, it says 'Couldn't find the requested content' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N3ow.png)

The frequency is pretty high, about 5-6 times a minute. I can see the same problem on the corresponding Cloudwatch page.  I don't know exactly how long this lasted and when it first happened, as there are so many wrong log streams. But as I scoll some pages I can confirm that this problem already exist before I update the code today, so it should not be caused by this code change.

The wrong log streams have the same content. And the behavior of the problem looks like the service cannot start, then ECS tries to restart it but fails again, forming an infinite loop.
But the thing is, my latest service starts successfully. I tested the API and verified that the servie is running fine.

What I expect is that there's a log stream for every run of the service. There must be something wrong with the errorneous logstreams constantly generated.

I tried inactivating/unregistering the old task definitions.But the problem is still not solved.

Comment: It sounds like your application is crashing and restarting and causing new log streams to be created each time. You may have another ECS service deployed that you are unaware of, or you could have a scheduled ECS task running that you are unaware of. ECS creates a log stream for each container it runs. You should check all of your ECS clusters, and disable the "running" filter in the ECS tasks view, so that you can see both running and stopped tasks.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the reply. Yes, the problem was caused by another service deployed and kept failing and restarting.   It turned out that my collegues created another cluster for testing purpose, including my service. But they used a wrong task definition revison and didn't change the log configuration. So the errorneous logstreams were sent to the same place as the cluster I was checking.